# UWP Timer Trigger Background Task Get's Suspended

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am working on BackgroundTask on UWP and have been trying to run this task but for some unknown reason it always ends up showing suspended in Task Manager and doesn't run. Below is the code

This how I am registering my BackgroundTask

```
    public static async Task InitializeLatestNewsTaskAsync()
    {
        TimeTrigger hourlyTrigger = new TimeTrigger(15, false);

        BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess();
        var requestStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager
            .RequestAccessKindAsync(BackgroundAccessRequestKind.AlwaysAllowed, "Please allow the app to run in background");

        if (!requestStatus)
        {
            Util.MessageBox("Warrning", "You will not receive any Announcements notifications");
        }
        else
        {
            try 
            {
                BackgroundTaskRegistration backgroundTaskRegistration = RegisterBackgroundTask(Constants.BACKGROUND_TASK_LATEST_NEWS_ENTRY_POINT,
                    Constants.BACKGROUND_TASK_LATEST_NEWS_NAME, hourlyTrigger, null);
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e.Message, e);
            }
        }
    }

    //
    // Register a background task with the specified taskEntryPoint, name, trigger,
    // and condition (optional).
    //
    // taskEntryPoint: Task entry point for the background task.
    // taskName: A name for the background task.
    // trigger: The trigger for the background task.
    // condition: Optional parameter. A conditional event that must be true for the task to fire.
    //
    private static BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(
        string taskEntryPoint, string taskName, IBackgroundTrigger trigger, IBackgroundCondition condition)
    {
        //
        // Check for existing registrations of this background task.
        //

        foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            if (cur.Value.Name == taskName)
            {
                //
                // The task is already registered.
                //
                BackgroundTaskRegistration backgroundTaskRegistration = (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);
                backgroundTaskRegistration.Unregister(true);
                break;
            }
        }

        //
        // Register the background task.
        //

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.Name = taskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
        builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
        builder.IsNetworkRequested = true;

        if (condition != null)
        {
            builder.AddCondition(condition);
        }

        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
        task.Completed += new BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler(OnCompleted);


        return task;
    }

    private static async void OnCompleted(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        log.Info("Completed");
    }
```

And Here is my Package.appxmanifest Declarations

[image]

and My BackgroundTask Implementation

```
public sealed class LatestNewsBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private ILogger log = LogManagerFactory.DefaultLogManager.GetLogger<LatestNewsBackgroundTask>();

    BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        log.Info("Latest New Background Task Started");

        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        taskInstance.Canceled += new BackgroundTaskCanceledEventHandler(OnCanceled);

        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        var announcementTypes = localSettings.Values["announcementTypes"];

        NotificationHelper.GenerateToast("working from background task ", announcementTypes.ToString());

        log.Info("Latest New Background Task Completed");

        _deferral.Complete();
    }

    private void OnCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        // Indicate that the background task is canceled.

        log.Info("Background " + sender.Task.Name + " Cancel Requested...");
    }
}
```

What all I have tried to debug

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/debug-a-background-task

Comment: Hello, when debugging a background task, can you enter the background task and execute it completely? If this step cannot be completed, please check if your task registration name is valid. If you can perform background tasks in the debugging state, then please check your Log file. I see that a log record is created in your code, you can check it to find the reason why it is not working.

Comment: Hi, i have verified the name is valid and it doesn’t enter the task execution and all i get it backgroundTask.exe exited. I tried everything but still don’t know why its not working

Comment: Hello, can you provide a minimal reproducible demo so that we can reproduce your problem (don't include any private information) and help you solve it.